# Responsive Images with the Umbraco Image Cropper

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want responsive images, like with `picture` elements or `srcset` attributes. I could easily accomplish automation in my Umbraco site using standard media pickers or whatever, and then something like this in the view:

```
<img src="@Model.Src.GetCropUrl(290)"
    srcset="@Model.Src.GetCropUrl(380) 420w, @Model.Src.GetCropUrl(700) 992w"/>
```

However, I rather like the Image Cropper property editor in Umbraco, which empowers the editors, so I'd like to utilize that. My problem here is that I find it hard to combine the results of the ready-made helpers like `GetCropUrl()` with responsiveness because of how all the parameters controlling the underlying `ImageProcessorModule` are included - i.e. changing just the width or height parameters of a `String` like:

```
/media/1013/myImage.jpg?crop=0,0.43395061728395062,0,0.31604938271604938&cropmode=percentage&width=2560&height=360&rnd=131213663460000000`
```

... Seems cumbersome at best ;)

After looking into the Umbraco source code I realized I could just de-serialize the Image Cropper data into the built in `ImageCropDataSet` type, like so:

```
var jsonCrop = content.GetPropertyValue<String>(imageFieldName);
var cropSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageCropDataSet>(jsonCrop, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
        });
```

This actually solves my problem - I get all I the information I need separately, and can then puzzle the pieces together in whatever manner I fancy - but the solution seems somewhat out-of-the-box.

Would the experienced Umbraco developer perhaps implement image responsiveness with the Image Cropper property editor in some other more Umbraco-standard-kind-of-way?